# What is this scene parodying?

Tags: plastic-neesan

In chapter 8 of *+Tic Neesan*, what is this scene parodying?

I don't get the references at all. :(

The only thing I could possibly link would be *Welcome to the NHK*'s anime mascot who has a similar catchphrase, but I doubt very much that it's the link.

[image: here]
[image]

Comment: This monk is Ikkyuu and the warrior guy is Shin'emon, both from *[Ikkyuu-san](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1461)*.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't explain why they are inside the tower on her head xD

Comment: All the other characters have things on their heads too - one has a tank :D

Comment: Do they also have people in there?

Comment: Not in what I've read so far, but it's a strange manga, so I wouldn't be suprised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Krazer.

The characters in the scene seem to be Ikkyuu and Shin'emon from [Ikkyū-san](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1461).

The low-effort scribbles are signifying that they are characters from another series and want to avoid copyright issues, like how many MacDonalds in anime are called WacDonalds or similar.

I think it's not parodying a particular scene but instead just making fun of Shin'emon's cleft chin:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

The only thing I can think of is the annoying anime series from within the series "Welcome to the NHK". Purrurin's theme song was blasting from next door in the first episode, antagonizing Sato's mental illness. His next door nieghbor, Yamazaki, was obsessed with the main character, and he references her several times as proof of his love of anime over real girls.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Which scene and how does it have a connection?

Comment: that sprang to mind for me aswell, but I couldn't make a logical connection to this scene/series. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if this were an older manga than "Welcome to the NHK", then, if I'm still right, at least partially, Purrurin in that series might have been based on an older idea.